# Magento 1.9 | Rating not displaying at product list

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, ratings

[image: products list]
Currently, on the list of products starts is displayed only when someone adds reviews. I need to display the stars and message to leave review and rating.
In template found that it should've been displayed "Be the first to review this product",but it's not.

Here is summary_short.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <span class="amount"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And corresponding part of rating block in list.phtml

```
                    <div class="item-content">
                        <?php
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo "{$this->escapeUrl($product->getProductUrl())}#customer-reviews"; ?>">
                            <?php if ($product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                                <?php if ($gc['display_rating'] == 1): //Display on hover ?>
                                    <div class="display-onhover ratings-wrapper">
                                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'short'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php elseif ($gc['display_rating'] == 2): //Always display ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'short'); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>

                    </div>
```

Comment: check this link --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370028/how-to-display-rating-summary-in-product-listing-in-magento

Comment: @MohitPatel Tried this code, it just shows stars and ratings only for products which has reviews. But doesn't shows stars for products with no reviews as I want.